# How can i testify that downloaded application is native or cross platform developed

Tags: android, cordova, cross-platform, titanium, google-play

I want to check for the existing apps on google play which technology is used in development for. Is that possible to figure out an application native or cross platform based like Titanium and Android in case of cross platform used. Can any body have any trick to find out so.

Comment: Do u find the solution from my answer Mr. Suresh Sharma???

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem By getting apk and try to decompile it . You will get source and resources.Then you will br able to identify it. [See this](http://yeblon.com/how-to-decompile-android-apk-app-files)

Answer (score 0):

You want to reverse engineer the apk file. Follow these steps:

1. Download dex2jar file from [here](http://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/).
2. open Command Prompt and change path as : C:\dex2jar and type cd C:\dex2jar and press enter. Place APK file in dex2jar folder after that type dex2jar FlagQuiz_1.1.apk to start decompiling it.
3. Download Java JD_GUI from [here](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui).
4. Open the converted jar file. There list of content will be displayed.